# Get image url from RSS Data

Tags: objective-c, image, get, rss

I have got a RSS parsing project.it's my RSS url;

http://vimeo.com/udhdhmi/videos/rss

I'm parsing with NSXMLParser methods.

```
- (void)rssParseStart{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/udhdhmi/videos/rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        model = [[VideoModel alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [model.videoTitle appendString:string];
    }
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [model.videoPubDate appendString:string];
    }
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [model.videoLink appendString:string];
    }
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [model.videoDescription appendString:string];
    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [feeds addObject:model];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

No problem up to this point but coming datas of from "Description" tags thus;
-example;

```
<p><a href="http://vimeo.com/107905906"><img src="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/491445051_200x150.jpg" alt="" /></a></p><p><p class="first"></p></p><p><strong>Cast:</strong> <a href="http://vimeo.com/udhdhmi">DHMI</a></p><p><strong>Tags:</strong> </p>
```

I want only image url adress from that data.
thank for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
- (void)rssParseStart{
    self.progressBar = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.progressBar.labelText = @"Lütfen bekleyiniz...";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/udhdhmi/videos/rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        model = [[VideoModel alloc]init];
    }
    if ([element isEqual:@"media:thumbnail"]) {
        NSString *imageURLString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
        [model.videoDescription appendString:imageURLString];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [model.videoTitle appendString:string];
    }
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [model.videoPubDate appendString:string];
    }
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [model.videoLink appendString:string];
    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [feeds addObject:model];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get url from that data by trimming the string value you get from xml parser

```
// it is assumed that 'string' variable holds your current data
NSRange range;
int index;

range = [string rangeOfString:@"img src=\""];
index = range.location + range.length;

NSString* trimmedString = [string substringFromIndex:index];

range = [trimmedString rangeOfString:@"\""];
index = range.location + range.length - 1;

NSString* finalValue = [trimmedString substringToIndex:index];
```

finalValue stores the url as a string